# PHP - How to submit a form containing input fields that point to different MySQL rows

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, codeigniter

I am setting up a form using this PHP that loops through all records a user may have:

```
    <?php foreach ($items as $row): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo form_hidden('id', $row->id); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo '<strong>' . $row->name . '</strong>'; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo form_input('number', $number); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo form_input('registry', $registry); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo form_checkbox('OK', $ok, $ok); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This gives me a form with the following look:

[image]

The idea here is that each row belongs to a unique ID/row in the database, and I would like to allow the user to edit all on the same page/form, using a single submit button.

What would be the best way of implementing this?

When this data is submitted, there should be a way of looping through each packet of information (from each user) in my controller. Would this be done via ajax/json?

Comment: You shouldn't be worrying about using ajax until you have the form working without it. What exactly *is* the issue, where are you stuck?

Comment: Each of the input type="text" need to have a unique name, and you will use php to GET or POST the name and their values.

Comment: @RPM - that brings up 2 issues -- (1) is there a way of submitting this data as a JSON string or array? -- (2) how do I loop though this data in my controller?

Comment: @torr I don't want to be 'that guy' but the easiest way to submit the form via Ajax is with 'jQuery Serialize' (google). You should get the form working without Ajax first though.

Comment: Yes, you can submit this via ajax in json format. I can put up a code snippet.

Comment: @torr you could also do it another way, and make the code longer, so it is not that simple for an average person to read.

Comment: @RPM - I'd be interested in seeing your JSON approach as well

Comment: @torr see my answer, I put a code snippet up. Note that the dat is the name of your form elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not use codeigntier, but you should be familiar with the general technique before attempting to use CI to shortcut this process. Codeigniter will help you with rendering the form elements, performing validation, escaping your input and performing your query - but it will only help you (do anything) if you understand the basic principles involved. Hope this helps

**MARKUP**

```
<form action="/process.php">
<div>
    <h2>GORDON</h2>
    <input type="text" name="user[1][number]" /> <!-- The number corresponds to the row id -->
    <input type="text" name="user[1][registry]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="user[1][ok]" value="1" />
</div>
<div>
    <h2>ANDY</h2>
    <input type="text" name="user[242][number]" />
    <input type="text" name="user[242][registry]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="user[242][ok]" value="1" />
</div>
<div>
    <h2>STEWART</h2>
    <input type="text" name="user[11][number]" />
    <input type="text" name="user[11][registry]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="user[11][ok]" value="1" />
</div>

<input type="submit" />
```

**PHP**

```
$users = $_REQUEST['user'];

foreach ($users as $rowId => $info){

    // YOU SHOULD MAKE SURE TO CLEAN YOUR INPUT - THIS IS A GUESS AT WHAT YOUR DATA TYPES MIGHT BE
    $id = (int) $rowId;
    $number = (int) $info['number'];
    $registry = mysql_real_escape_string($info['registry']);
    $ok = (int) ($info['ok']);

    $q = "UPDATE user SET number = $number, registry = '$registry', ok = $ok WHERE id = $id";
    mysql_query($q);

    // You may want to check that the above query was sucessful and log any errors etc.

}
```

Comment: Are you sure he should be using $_REQUEST? I would think the most optimal way would be via $_GET or $_POST

Comment: Yep - but I don't know how he is submitting the form. It is indeed better to use Get or Post although Request will also work. It isn't however best practice.

Comment: this form is loaded and submitted via ajax - for submit I use malup's jQuery Form plugin -- for clarity I did not put this info the OP since I think this could be solved without using ajax etc

Comment: @torr Well - let me know if you need any more help - it seems your question has been answered.

Comment: @kissmyface are you aware if this method breaks when using a checkbox? everything seems to work, except the POST for the checkbox, and I end up getting an undefined variable after submitting

Comment: solved it -- the unchecked (empty) value from a checkbox needs to be set to '0' in my controller -- checked boxes cause no problems -- thanks for you help and thorough answer @kissmyface

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use ajax mate.

For each  put a hidden input with the ID of the row in this format:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[<?= $row->id ?>]" value="<?= $row->id ?>" ?>
```

Do the same for each element in the tr, i.e. name them as

```
name="number[<?= $row->$id ?>]"
name="registry[<?=$row->$id ?>]"
name="ok[<?=$row->$id ?>]"
```

and once you post the FORM you can iterate each row with:

```
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $_POST['name'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up input-names as array-names, so you will send the whole form and may iterate over the entries.

e.g.

```
<?php
echo form_input('userdata[' . $row->id . '][number]', $number);
?>
```

which would possibly create an

```
<input name="userdata[1][number]" />
```

(I don't know where those form-functions came from…)

This will result in an array `$_POST['userdata']` which may be iterated via:

```
foreach($_POST['userdata'] as $userId => $userInputFields)
{
    $user = new User($userId);
    $user->number = $userInputFields['number'];
    // …
}
```